# TableViewCell remains selected/highlighted will this be rejected by apple

Tags: iphone

I have a tableview with a TableViewCell that remains selected/highlighted.  When a user goes to the detail section, and returns, the selected row remains highlighted.

So, will they reject this app? Kindly let me know :(

Thanks

Comment: ??? are they going to reject my app if one of table view cells remains selected??

Comment: What do you mean?! It remains selected when what? It remains selected but it shouldn't? Then fix it. I don't see the problem here and your question is pretty confusing.

Comment: try this  [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone]; in your cellForRowatindexPath..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you get your app rejected and upload it again, it won't be of any use, since it will be rejected for the same reason.

But, Apple doesn't just reject an app for a reason like "Your table cell remains selected and we don't like that". Apple can possibly reject you for the reason you have to keep your cell highlighted like that. If you have a good reason to keep your cell rejected, it won't bother them and it'll get accepted. If it gets rejected, they'll give you a reason and you can (should!) adapt your app accordingly.

Comment: so better not to reject binary , and wait for them  since my app is in Review , what you suggest??

Comment: @prajakta: It totally depends on why you kept the cell highlighted. I don't know that since I don't know about your app, but if you have a good reason to use it, it won't get rejected. Apple will look at that the same way I described, and they will accept it if it's ok with them. They will reject it if it's not, and they'll give a reason for it. Long story short: sit the wait out and see what Apple has to say about it ;)

Comment: @prajakta: Don't worry about it too much. If it gets rejected, just adapt your app untill you think it's fine again, and resend it :) Nothing bad happens if it gets rejected ;)

Answer (score 1):

in your didSelectRow method write this:-

```
[*yourtableview* deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Comment: my app is in Review , now cant do anything :(

Comment: its in review for the last 24 hrs damn how long need to wait ..:(